# Select all forms in the page and serialize their input values

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jqueryform

Hello i am trying to Select all forms in the page and then serialize their input values, i am using the following code:

```
function serializeAllFormData() {
                        var serializedData;
                        $("#form").each(
                                function() {
                                    serializedData = serializedData
                                            + $(this).serialize();
                                });
                        return serializedData;
                    }
```

but when i inspect serializedData it is undefined, what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

You are selecting the forms as if they were an ID `#form` (the hash sign `#` is only used when selecting on an ID). Try using just `form` instead.

```
$("form").each(function() {
   serializedData = serializedData + $(this).serialize();
});
```

**Update**

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) the each function can take a first argument (indexInArray). So you could do something like this:

```
var forms = $("form");
forms.each(function(i) {
   serializedData = serializedData + $(this).serialize();

   // i will start a 0, therefor forms.length - 1 in the if-statement
   if (i === forms.length - 1) {
      // Do something on the last element
   }
});
```

*I cache the forms in a variable so that we don't have to go through the DOM every time the loop runs.*

Comment: How do i know in each the last form element? if(form==last) do someting

Answer (score 0):

fixed by

```
function serializeAllFormData() {
                        var serializedData;
                        var forms = $('#content').find('form');
                        $(forms).each(
                                function() {
                                    serializedData = serializedData
                                            + $(this).serialize();
                                });
                        alert(serializedData);
                        return serializedData;
                    }
```